# The derivate class dosn't behave like the base when i pass parameter to them

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have done a class hierarchy for product several plot stile , in which change almost any parameter, just inherit and define a set of parameter for change the default plot ..

but I have some problem with the derived class , basically from the abstract base class 
derive a complete and usable class which is callable ! (in this way i can call directly subplot, or plot referring to the derived class)

The problem is that the usable base class that define the method `__call__`  works fine and accept and use in the right way the parameter passed by a generic script that instantiate it for create a plot, the derivatives classes don't.

here I'm report minimal working code

the base abstract class is:

```
class BasePlot(metaclass=ABCMeta):

   def __init__(self, title : str = ' ' , filename : str = ' '):
      self.title = title
      self.filename = filename   

   def schemes(self, style:str = 'nb'):
       if style == 'nb':
            return ['#8DA0CB', '#E58AC3', '#A6D853', '#FFD930', '#B2B2B2', '#5FC3A4', '#FC8D62', '#66C2A5']
       elif style == 'vega':
            return  ['#1F77B4', '#FF7F0E', '#2CA02C', '#D62728', '#9467BD', '#8C564B', '#E377C2', '#7F7F7F', '#BCBD22', '#17BECF']
```

from this base class derive the "Default plot" before called "the usable base class"

```
class DefaultPlot(BasePlot) :

    def __init__(self, figsize,*args,**kwargs):
        self.var = [*args]
        self.params = kwargs

    def cycle(self,n : str):
            if n == '0':
                  return plt.cycler("color", self.schemes(self.parameters['scheme']) )      #colors)         
            elif n=='1':
                  return plt.cycler("color", self.schemes(self.parameters['scheme']) ) + plt.cycler("linestyle", self.linestyles(self.parameters['linestyle']))

    def setparams(self, kwargs):
             self.parameters = kwargs

             if 'scheme' not in self.parameters.keys():
                self.parameters['scheme'] = self.schemes('nb')


             myparams = {
               'axes.prop_cycle': 0,     

             }

             plt.rcParams.update(myparams)

    def __call__ (self,nrows,ncols,*args,**kwargs):

       self.setparams(kwargs)


            self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots(nrows,ncols,figsize=(9.5,4.5))
```

then the derivate class for which the parameter passed as dictionary dosen't affect 
the parameters (as expected ... here is the problem)

```
#-*- coding : utf-8 -*- 


class Standard(DefaultPlot):

    def __init__(self , figsize , *args , **kwargs):
        self.args = [*args]
        self.params = kwargs
        super().__init__(figsize,*self.args, **self.params )

    def setparams(self, kwargs):

             self.parameters = kwargs
             if 'scheme' in self.parameters.keys():
                self.parameters['scheme'] = 'nb' 
             if 'cycle' not in self.parameters.keys():
                self.parameters['cycle']  = self.cycle('0')

             super().setparams(self.parameters)
```

and finally the script in which the class is called :

```
import defaultplot 
import qualityplot

def main():

    x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
    y1 = np.sin(x)
    y2 = np.sin(2*x)
    y3 = np.sin(3*x)

    fig,axs = qualityplot.Standard(figsize=(9.5,4.5))(1,1,**{'scheme':'vega'})
    #fig,axs = defaultplot.DefaultPlot(figsize=(9.5,4.5))(1,1,**{'scheme':'vega'})

    axs.plot(x,y1,x,y2,x,y3)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this script above the Standard class is instantiate and a dictionary containing parameters is passed , in particular the parameter for the scheme colors ! 
even thought the code works the result is not was I expected indeed the scheme 'vega' is not used in the plot ! while if you call in the same way the base class (the commented call) the code use the scheme 'vega' !! whyy ??? what I'm wronging ?

**EDIT** I'm sorry if you spend time to understand this messy code ! this morning I've look this and I was yelling versus myself  ... I fixed this mess and revrite all the things clear !

i think that in order to be correct with who spent time trying to help me I have to apologize ...

the solution is straightforward : think before post !
for who is interested the solution code :

```
  class BasePlot(metaclass=ABCMeta):

   def __init__(self,figsize,**kwargs):
      self.figsize = figsize
      self.params = kwargs   

   def schemes(self, style:str = 'nb'):
       if style == 'nb':
            return ['#8DA0CB', '#E58AC3', '#A6D853', '#FFD930', '#B2B2B2', '#5FC3A4', '#FC8D62', '#66C2A5']
       elif style == 'nb2':
            return  ['#82A6C7', '#DAADEB', '#99D366', '#FFD930', '#B2B2B2', '#5FC3A4', '#FC8D62', '#66C2A5']
       elif style == 'vega':
            return  ['#1F77B4', '#FF7F0E', '#2CA02C', '#D62728', '#9467BD', '#8C564B', '#E377C2', '#7F7F7F', '#BCBD22', '#17BECF']
```

the default class

```
class DefaultPlot(BasePlot) :

    def __init__(self, figsize, **kwargs):
        self.figsize = figsize
        self.parameters = kwargs
        #print(self.parameters)
        self.setparams(self.parameters)
    def cycle(self,n : str):
            if n == '0':
                  return plt.cycler("color", self.schemes(self.parameters['scheme']) )      #colors)         
            elif n=='1':
                  return plt.cycler("color", self.schemes(self.parameters['scheme']) ) + plt.cycler("linestyle", self.linestyles(self.parameters['linestyle']))

    def setparams(self, kwargs):
             print(self.parameters)
             self.parameters.update(kwargs)

             if 'font' not in self.parameters.keys():
                self.parameters['font'] = 'serif'
             if 'cycle' not in self.parameters.keys():
                self.parameters['cycle']  = self.cycle('0')
             if 'linestyles' not in self.parameters.keys():
                self.parameters['linestyles'] = self.linestyles('paper')
             if 'scheme' not in self.parameters.keys():
                self.parameters['scheme'] = 'nb'
             if 'linestyle' not in self.parameters.keys():
                self.parameters['linestyle'] = self.linestyles('ls2')

             print('*' ,self.parameters['scheme'])

             myparams = {
               'axes.prop_cycle': self.parameters['cycle'],     
               'grid.color' : 'gray',
               'font.family': self.parameters['font'] ,
               'font.style' : 'italic'

             }

             plt.rcParams.update(myparams)


    def __call__ (self,nrows,ncols,figsize=(9,6)):
       self.nrows = nrows
       self.ncols = ncols
       self.figsize = figsize
       if self.nrows == self.ncols ==1:
            self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots(self.nrows,self.ncols,figsize=self.figsize)
       else:
            self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots(self.nrows,self.ncols,figsize=self.figsize)
```

the quality (final derived)

```
from  defaultplot import DefaultPlot

class Standard(DefaultPlot):

    def __init__(self , figsize , **kwargs):
        self.figsize = figsize
        self.parameters = kwargs


        print(self.parameters)
        self.setparams(self.parameters)
        print(self.parameters)
        super().__init__(figsize,**self.parameters )

    def setparams(self, kwargs):
             print(kwargs, '#')
             self.parameters.update(kwargs)

             if 'scheme' not in self.parameters.keys():
                self.parameters['scheme'] = 'nb' 
             if 'linestyles' not in self.parameters.keys():
                self.parameters['linestyles'] = self.linestyles('paper')
             if 'cycle' not in self.parameters.keys():
                self.parameters['cycle']  = self.cycle('0')

             super().setparams(self.parameters)
```

and the script that call :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import defaultplot 
import qualityplot

def main():

    x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
    y1 = np.sin(x)
    y2 = np.sin(2*x)
    y3 = np.sin(3*x)

    fig,axs = qualityplot.Standard(figsize=(9.5,4.5) , **{'scheme':'vega'})(1,1)
    #fig,axs = defaultplot.DefaultPlot(figsize=(9.5,4.5), **{'scheme':'vega'})(1,1, figsize=(9.5,4.5))

    axs.plot(x,y1,x,y2,x,y3)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**EDIT**
my complete **call** is

```
   def __call__ (self,nrows,ncols,figsize=(9.5,4.5)):

       self.nrows = nrows 
       self.ncols = ncols 
       self.figsize = figsize
       #self.figsize = self.parameters['figure.figsize'] 

       if self.nrows == self.ncols ==1:
            self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots( self.nrows, self.ncols,figsize=self.figsize)
       else:
            self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots( self.nrows, self.ncols,figsize=self.figsize)

       self.fig,self.axs = self.set( self.nrows, self.ncols,self.fig,self.axs, self.parameters )
       return  self.fig,self.axs
```

Comment: If all you want to do is change plotting styles, why not simply create a `matplotlib` [style](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) for each?

Comment: because there is some parameters that is not possible to define in rcparams .. like the grid( dashes=(5,9)) and I prefer have a hierarchy ... for me it is more powerful ... could you help me about my problem ?

Comment: Can you please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates your issue? The code you posted above is neither minimal nor verifiable. It contains unused code and does not run the way you posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm doing this in an answer because I cannot possibly handle all this in the comments.

Mate, I hate to break it to you but:

1. your code example is still way too extensive and
2. both, the `Standard` and the `DefaultPlot` instance behave exactly the same when given the same attributes.

Let me break that down for you.
Your main issue is that you (now) call `setparams` three times when instantiating `Standard`.

1. On your `Standard` object, setting `scheme`, `cycle` and `linestyles` to their respective defaults.
2. On the `Standard` object's super class directly from `Standard.setparams`, where you set `scheme`, `cycle` and `linestyles` to the very same defaults and add some for `linestyle` and `font`.
3. When calling `super().__init__(...)` from your `Standard` object which completely repeats 2. above.

Also, doing `self.parameters.update(kwargs)` at the beginning of `setparams` achieves absolutely nothing, you update `self.params` to exactly what it already is a this point.

The following example does exactly the same as your second example, after stripping away all the calls to pyplot (that are not relevant for this example context here) and all the code that is not used in what you posted.

Maybe you can try to explain your goal using the below. Or you might even be able to go from here and figure out what you need to do to get what you are looking for.

```
import abc


class BasePlot(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    @abc.abstractmethod  # this ensures that BasePlot cannot be instantiated
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.parameters = kwargs
        self.figsize = None  # in your example, you use figsize only in __call__
        self.nrows = None  # declare your instance attributes in the cunstructor
        self.ncols = None  # declare your instance attributes in the cunstructor
        self.setparams()  # I would probably add this to __call__ instead of having it here


    def setparams(self):
        if 'font' not in self.parameters.keys():
            self.parameters['font'] = 'serif'
        if 'cycle' not in self.parameters.keys():
            self.parameters['cycle'] = self.cycle('0')
        if 'linestyles' not in self.parameters.keys():
            self.parameters['linestyles'] = "paper"
        if 'scheme' not in self.parameters.keys():
            self.parameters['scheme'] = 'nb'
        if 'linestyle' not in self.parameters.keys():
            self.parameters['linestyle'] = "ls2"


    def cycle(self, n: str):
        # this is just a stub method, let it do whatever you need it to do
        if n == '0':
            return "cycle is 1"
        elif n == '1':
            return "cycle is 2"


    def __call__(self, nrows, ncols, figsize=(9, 6)):
        self.nrows = nrows
        self.ncols = ncols
        self.figsize = figsize
        # this is just a stub method, let it do whatever you need it to do
        print(self.parameters)
        return self.nrows, self.ncols, self.figsize


class DefaultPlot(BasePlot):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):  # needed here because the contract requires __init__ to be implemented
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class Standard(DefaultPlot):
    pass


def main():

    print(Standard(**{'scheme': 'vega'})(1, 1))
    print("="*20)
    print(DefaultPlot(**{'scheme': 'vega'})(1, 1, figsize=(9.5, 4.5)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# Output:
# {'scheme': 'vega', 'font': 'serif', 'cycle': 'cycle is 1', 'linestyles': 'paper', 'linestyle': 'ls2'}
# (1, 1, (9, 6))
# ====================
# {'scheme': 'vega', 'font': 'serif', 'cycle': 'cycle is 1', 'linestyles': 'paper', 'linestyle': 'ls2'}
# (1, 1, (9.5, 4.5))
```

Let me know when you figured out what you need, so that I can delete this answer; or edit it if there's still questions left.

Comment: thanks a lot !! I know that my code it's a messy code !! in particular is crap from the software design point of view ... Any advice here is welcome !!! :)

Comment: but call should return `self.fig` and `self.axs`

Comment: As I said, I simplified it, to have something that I can run since your code was neither minimal, nor verifiable or complete. If you need  `__call__` to do something else, then add your code in (although I don't see the point of your `if`-`else` condition; both logical paths behave the same). Also, you can put back your code in `cycle` which I stripped down as well. My main question is: what do you want to achieve? With the above structure (that behaves just as your latest code), there is no point in having inheritance. `Standard` and `DefaultPlot` have no functional difference.

Comment: Thank you very much !! thanks to your advice I rewrote the baseclass , delete the default one (doesn't need ) and create a better project of hierarchy for producing "quality" (from my point of view me) plot !!

Comment: @Drudoxlebowsky good that you took something away from this. However, please consider deleting this question. As it stands it is too specific to be of help for anyone else and the problem description does not match your desired solution anymore.